# (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i developed an game

in this game users can login by FaceBook API then share there best score on facebook by score api.

but when i login in game by my Facebook account every things is worked and whene i login by other account i got this error:

> (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions

and this my code:

```
public void postScore() {

        final int score = getScore();
        Log.i(TAG, "" + score);
        if (score > 0) {
            // Only post the score if they smashed at least one friend!
            // Post the score to FB (for score stories and distribution)
            Bundle fbParams = new Bundle();
            fbParams.putString("score", "" + score);
            Request postScoreRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
                    "me/scores", fbParams, HttpMethod.POST,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onCompleted");
                            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                            if (error != null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Posting Score to Facebook failed: "
                                        + error.getErrorMessage());

                            } else {
                                Log.i(TAG,
                                        "Score posted successfully to Facebook");
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Request.executeBatchAsync(postScoreRequest);
        }
    }
```

please help me.

Comment: Seems like an authentication issue with the other APIs.

Comment: Have your app passed review? If you need the publish_actions permission then you need to request it via App Review.

Comment: Tank you **@MingLi**, App Review for me is completed, i get **"publish_actions"** & **"user_games_activity"** permission completly. i still got this error. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve problem by this steps:

**Step1**:

```
postButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (session == null || !session.isOpened()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Session is null!");
                return;
            }
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!permissions.contains("publish_actions")) {
                // the user didn't grant this permission, so we need to
                // prompt them.
                askForPublishActionsForScores();
                return;
            } else {
                ReadAndWriteFBscore.postScore();
            }

        }
    });
```

**Step2**:

```
private void askForPublishActionsForScores() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setPositiveButton("بله",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User hit OK. Request Facebook friends
                            // permission.
                            requestPublishPermissions();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("خیر",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User hit cancel.


                        }
                    }).setTitle(R.string.publish_scores_dialog_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.publish_scores_dialog_message).show();
 }
```

**Step3**:

```
void requestPublishPermissions() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Requesting publish permissions.");
    final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new      Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                this, PERMISSIONS)
                // demonstrate how to set an audience for the publish
                // permissions,
                // if none are set, this defaults to FRIENDS
                .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS)
                .setRequestCode(AUTH_PUBLISH_ACTIONS_SCORES_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
}
```

**Step4**:

```
private static final int AUTH_PUBLISH_ACTIONS_SCORES_ACTIVITY_CODE = 103;
```